# golang rpc with protobuf compile difference?

Tags: grpc

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

service Hpgrpcservice {
    rpc QuotationSettleData(stream QuotationReqData) returns (stream SettleResData) {}
}
```

then I compile it as

```
protoc --proto_path=./hpgrpc  --go_out=./hpgrpc  ./hpgrpc/hp.proto
```

expect in hp.pb.go has server and client code but have not. but if use

```
protoc --proto_path=./hpgrpc ./hpgrpc/hp.proto  --go_out=plugins=grpc:hpgrpc
```

it will has server and client code. what difference about this 2 complile way?

Answer (score 0):

If a proto file specifies RPC services, protoc-gen-go can be instructed to generate code compatible with gRPC (http://www.grpc.io/). To do this, pass the plugins parameter to protoc-gen-go; the usual way is to insert it into the --go_out argument to protoc:

```
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
```

In your second code, since you have mentioned plugins=grpc, the pb.go file is also having grpc Support.

For more details, you can go through this : https://github.com/golang/protobuf